# Website form to send to email

Tags: php, html, forms

I am a beginner at all this,

I am trying to get a enquiry form to capture the information in the form and email it to my email address.

What is the easiest way to get the form to do this ,

the form code is below. I am actually playing around with 2 different forms on this test page www.golfingholidays.ie/test.html

Any help or advice would be much appreciated

```
<div id="booking"></div>
<div id="book">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="mid">  
        <div id="form">

            Name <input type="text" /><br />
            Telephone Number &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;<input type="text" /><br />
            Email Address <input type="text" /><br />
            Address <input type="text"  /><br />

            Destination
            <select> 
                <option>Please Select</option>
                <option>Portugal</option>
                <option>Spain</option>
                <option>Tenerife</option>
                <option>Gran Canaria</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            Number of People 
            <select>
                <option>&nbsp;--&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;01&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;02&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;03&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;04&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;05&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;06&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;07&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;08&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;09&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;10+&nbsp;</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            Duration 
            <select>
                <option>&nbsp;--&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;01&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;02&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;03&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;04&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;05&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;06&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;07&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;08&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;09+&nbsp;</option>
            </select>
            <br />

            Accom
            <select>
                <option>Please Select</option>
                <option>Apartments</option>
                <option>2** Hotel</option>
                <option>3*** Hotel</option>
                <option>4**** Hotel</option>
                <option>5***** Hotel</option>
            </select>

            <br />  Number of Rounds
            <select>
                <option>&nbsp;--&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;01&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;02&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;03&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;04&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;05&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;06&nbsp;</option>
                <option>&nbsp;07+&nbsp;</option>
            </select>

            <br />
            <div>Car Hire
                <input type="checkbox" name="Yes" value="Yes"/>Yes
                <input type="checkbox" name="no" value="no" />No
            </div>
            <br />

            Other <input type="text">
            <a id="button" href="#">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: why not try built in function of php.It does has mail function

Comment: You can't just put everything in <div> tags and expect it to all work, you need to use the right tags for the job.  <form>, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

For example

**your html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>  
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <title>send mail in php</title>  
    <style type="text/css">  
        li {list-style-type: none;  
            font-size: 16pt;  
        }  
        .mail {  
            margin: auto;  
            padding-top: 10px;  
            padding-bottom: 10px;  
            width: 400px;  
            background : #D8F1F8;  
            border: 1px solid silver;  
        }  
        .mail h2 {  
            margin-left: 38px;  
        }  
        input {  
            font-size: 20pt;  
        }  
        input:focus, textarea:focus{  
            background-color: lightyellow;  
        }  
        input submit {  
            font-size: 12pt;  
        }  
    </style>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <div class="mail">  
        <h2>Mail us</h2>  
        <ul>  
            <li><form name="mail" method="POST" action="send.php"></li>  
            <li>To:</li>  
            <li><input type="text" name="to" /></li>  
            <li>Subject:</li>  
            <li><input type="text" name="subject" /></li>  
            <li>Message:</li>  
            <li><input type="text" name="Message" /></li>  
            <li>&nbsp;</li>  
            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/></li>  
            <li>&nbsp;</li>  
            </form>  
        </ul>  
    </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code of the file for handling form (code above) data**

```
<?php  
    $to = $_POST['to'] ;      
    $message = $_POST['Message'] ;  
    mail( $to, "Mail", $message,  );  
    header( "Location: http://localhost/php/simple-mail.php" );  
?>
```

I hope this would give you idea

Comment: Please add: exit(); after header( "Location: http://localhost/php/simple-mail.php" ); 
Otherwise the script execution is not terminated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan to use PHP, but only HTML, you can use a service like [elFormo.com](https://www.elformo.com). They even have a free plan.